# How to print variables in Perl

Tags: perl

I have some code that looks like

```
my ($ids,$nIds);
while (<myFile>){
    chomp;
    $ids.= $_ . " ";
    $nIds++;
}
```

This should concatenate every line in my `myFile`, and `nIds` should be my number of lines. How do I print out my `$ids` and `$nIds`?

I tried simply `print $ids`, but Perl complains.

```
my ($ids, $nIds)
```

is a list, right? With two elements?

Comment: -1 for "Perl complains" rather than sharing the text of the actual message.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

```
print "Number of lines: $nids\n";
print "Content: $ids\n";
```

How did Perl complain?  `print $ids` should work, though you probably want a newline at the end, either explicitly with `print` as above or implicitly by using `say` or [-l](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#*-l*%5B_octnum_%5D)/[$\](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#$%5C).

If you want to interpolate a variable in a string and have something immediately after it that would looks like part of the variable but isn't, enclose the variable name in `{}`:

```
print "foo${ids}bar";
```

Comment: hey, just wondering, what if I want to print something immediately after the variable, i.e., I want to achieve this: `print "Content: $idsHeyIamhere"`

Answer (score 13):

You should always include all relevant code when asking a question. In this case, the print statement that is the center of your question. The print statement is probably the most crucial piece of information. The second most crucial piece of information is the error, which you also did not include. Next time, include both of those.

`print $ids` should be a fairly hard statement to mess up, but it is possible. Possible reasons:

1. `$ids` is undefined. Gives the warning `undefined value in print`
2. `$ids` is out of scope. With `use
   strict`, gives fatal warning `Global
   variable $ids needs explicit package
   name`, and otherwise the undefined
   warning from above.
3. You forgot a semi-colon at the end of
   the line.
4. You tried to do `print $ids $nIds`,
   in which case perl thinks that `$ids`
   is supposed to be a filehandle, and
   you get an error such as `print to
   unopened filehandle`.

**Explanations**

1: Should not happen. It *might* happen if you do something like this (assuming you are not using `strict`):

```
my $var;
while (<>) {
    $Var .= $_;
}
print $var;
```

Gives the warning for undefined value, because `$Var` and `$var` are two different variables.

2: Might happen, if you do something like this:

```
if ($something) {
    my $var = "something happened!";
}
print $var;
```

`my` declares the variable inside the current block. Outside the block, it is out of scope.

3: Simple enough, common mistake, easily fixed. Easier to spot with `use warnings`.

4: Also a common mistake. There are a number of ways to correctly print two variables in the same `print` statement:

```
print "$var1 $var2";  # concatenation inside a double quoted string
print $var1 . $var2;  # concatenation
print $var1, $var2;   # supplying print with a list of args
```

---

Lastly, some perl magic tips for you:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

# open with explicit direction '<', check the return value
# to make sure open succeeded. Using a lexical filehandle.
open my $fh, '<', 'file.txt' or die $!;

# read the whole file into an array and
# chomp all the lines at once
chomp(my @file = <$fh>);
close $fh;

my $ids  = join(' ', @file);
my $nIds = scalar @file;
print "Number of lines: $nIds\n";
print "Text:\n$ids\n";
```

Reading the whole file into an array is suitable for small files only, otherwise it uses a lot of memory. Usually, line-by-line is preferred.

Variations:

- `print "@file"` is equivalent to
  `$ids = join(' ',@file); print $ids;`
- `$#file` will return the last index
  in `@file`. Since arrays usually start at 0,
  `$#file + 1` is equivalent to `scalar @file`.

You can also do:

```
my $ids;
do {
    local $/;
    $ids = <$fh>;
}
```

By temporarily "turning off" `$/`, the input record separator, i.e. newline, you will make `<$fh>` return the entire file. What `<$fh>` really does is read until it finds `$/`, then return that string. Note that this will preserve the newlines in `$ids`.

Line-by-line solution:

```
open my $fh, '<', 'file.txt' or die $!; # btw, $! contains the most recent error
my $ids;
while (<$fh>) {
    chomp;
    $ids .= "$_ "; # concatenate with string
}
my $nIds = $.; # $. is Current line number for the last filehandle accessed.
```

Comment: Are you sure? When I say `$array[500] = "yada"`  the I get the value 501 for `scalar @array`.

Answer (score 9):

> How do I print out my $ids and $nIds?

```
print "$ids\n";
print "$nIds\n";
```

> I tried simply `print $ids`, but Perl complains.

Complains about what? Uninitialised value? Perhaps your loop was never entered due to an error opening the file. Be sure to check if `open` returned an error, and make sure you are using `use strict; use warnings;`.

> `my ($ids, $nIds)` is a list, right? With two elements?

It's a (very special) function call. `$ids,$nIds` is a list with two elements.